# Sonar Short Live Branch Scan Failing with Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

We have scanned the master code in Sonar and then we have update our Pom file to integrate with internal master pom and changed packages name. After that sonar of that branch and other branches started to fail with Null pointer exception. I don't have any clue on what is wrong here and need some expert advice. Please help me out on this.

I have tried multiple commands combination but nothing works, but the same command for master branch works fine.

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.branch.name=shankar -Dsonar.login=[token]
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd"
          xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <pluginGroups>
        <pluginGroup>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</pluginGroup>
    </pluginGroups>

    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>artifactory</id>
            <mirrorOf>external:*,!central,!spring,!security</mirrorOf>
            <name>Artifactory Pro</name>
            <url>https://artifactory.trusted.company.com/mavenrepo</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>sonar</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <sonar.host.url>
                    https://sonarqube.trusted.company.com
                </sonar.host.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

```
[INFO] 12:09:11.218 SCM collecting changed files in the branch
[DEBUG] 12:09:11.237 readpipe [git, --version],/usr/local/bin
[DEBUG] 12:09:11.253 readpipe may return 'git version 2.10.1'
[DEBUG] 12:09:11.255 remaining output:

[DEBUG] 12:09:11.255 readpipe [git, config, --system, --edit],/usr/local/bin
[DEBUG] 12:09:11.271 readpipe may return '/usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig'
[DEBUG] 12:09:11.272 remaining output:

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  55.152 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-15T12:09:11+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar (default-cli) on project card-issuance-ms: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.phases.PostJobsExecutor: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ScannerExtensionDictionnary: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.sensor.DefaultSensorContext: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.DefaultModuleFileSystem: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.StatusDetection: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scm.ScmChangedFiles: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar (default-cli) on project card-issuance-ms: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scm.ScmChangedFiles
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (ComponentContainer.java:65)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance (BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance (ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter (SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments (ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run (ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe (AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance (ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance (AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance (AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance (Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance (DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (ComponentContainer.java:63)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (DefaultPicoContainer.java:621)
    at org.picocontainer.containers.ImmutablePicoContainer.getComponent (ImmutablePicoContainer.java:40)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance (DefaultPicoContainer.java:718)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (ComponentContainer.java:63)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance (BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance (ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter (SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments (ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run (ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe (AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance (ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance (AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance (AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance (Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance (DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (ComponentContainer.java:63)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance (BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance (ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter (SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments (ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run (ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe (AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance (ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance (AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance (AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance (Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance (DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (ComponentContainer.java:63)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance (BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance (ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter (SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments (ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run (ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe (AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance (ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance (AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance (AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance (Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance (DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (ComponentContainer.java:63)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance (BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance (ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter (SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments (ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run (ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe (AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance (ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance (AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance (AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance (Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance (DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (ComponentContainer.java:63)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance (BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance (ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter (SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments (ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run (ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe (AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance (ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance (AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance (AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance (Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance (DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (ComponentContainer.java:63)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent (DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType (ComponentContainer.java:281)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart (ModuleScanContainer.java:164)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents (ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute (ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan (ProjectScanContainer.java:319)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively (ProjectScanContainer.java:314)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart (ProjectScanContainer.java:288)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents (ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute (ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute (ScanTask.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart (TaskContainer.java:82)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents (ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute (ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask (GlobalContainer.java:131)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask (Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute (Batch.java:71)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute (BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke (IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.execute (Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute (EmbeddedScanner.java:185)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute (EmbeddedScanner.java:137)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute (ScannerBootstrapper.java:65)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectIdOwnerMap.get (ObjectIdOwnerMap.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.parseAny (RevWalk.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.parseCommit (RevWalk.java:800)
    at org.sonarsource.scm.git.GitScmProvider.prepareTreeParser (GitScmProvider.java:196)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sonar - Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectLock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669506/sonar-unable-to-load-component-class-org-sonar-scanner-scan-projectlock)

Comment: No its not the same problem, the exception stacktrace is different

Comment: The error occurs in JGit, the library we are using to interact with Git. Very often this error is caused by shallow clones, but it may also be a bug in the library. Could you please provide the version of the sonar-scm-git plugin installed in your SonarQube server?

Comment: Hi @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam Please find the details.
Sonar plugin in Bitbucket is 2.2.2 ; Git plugin in Sonar is 1.7
Svn 1.9.0.1295 (scmsvn)
Git 1.7.0.1491 (scmgit)

Comment: Try to update to sonar-scm-git-plugin 1.8.0.1574 and [unshallow](https://github.com/SonarSource/travis-utils/blob/dbe10b856eaca84613de98d06b0677cd474ff030/bin/regular_gradle_build_deploy_analyze#L37) your repository before the analysis

Comment: Sure @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam Will try and keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer as said by @Julien H. - SonarSource Team is one of the solutions to this problem

Update to sonar-scm-git-plugin
or
Unshallow your repository before the analysis

I did the same and got a successful build.